# Editing Ruby files in a running heroku

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, vim, emacs

I have a Ruby project running on Heroku. I have to do some debugging on the live version (it's the one connected to AWS, which is where the bug is) The method I understand to do this is:

- Edit my copy
- push to heroku
- wait for it to confirm everything, some of which will probably fail
  because I don't care
- run the test
- lather rinse repeat

This takes a long time. if I could do this on my own machine, I would just edit, and see what it does. Is there a way to do this on Heroku? I've seen a VIM package, but I'm not sure that that's editing the files that are running? And I'd prefer to use an emacs package anyway... (I'll use VIM if necessary)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can connect to a web dyno but there is no text editor installed there. At least I've tried it and there wasn't any.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to get emacs to open it remotely, like ange-ftp or something...

Comment: Actually a quick google search "edit files on heroku" returns something. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone your heroku repo as follow:

```
$heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

make your changes and push it again

```
$git add .
$git commit -m "whatever commit"
$git push heroku master.
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose. Every time I do a git push, it goes through a whole several minute testing/rebuilding process and restarts the entire server. I don't need to do that. I just want to edit some files with quick turn-around.

Answer (score 0):

You might need this.

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/naaman/heroku-vim
https://github.com/naaman/heroku-vim
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that but it didn't work easily... maybe I just didn't set it up correctly... I'll have to futz with that I guess.